# Gridview Re-size for cell data ASP

Tags: css, asp.net

Hi I am trying to fix my Gridview in ASP so the columns are bigger according the the cell data.

Here is what it looks like:

http://s18.postimg.org/hjw6dwrmh/Capture.png

Here is the code I am using for this Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="7" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" AllowSorting="True">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Template fields on yor gridview. You will need to set  AutoGenerateColumns to False then build your columns.

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField>
>                <ItemTemplate>
>                <asp:label id="labelid" text='<%#Eval("Features")%>' runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:label>
>                </ItemTemplate>
>                </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to generate the columns declaratively instead of letting gridview auto generate columns. You can set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` at the gridview definition and define your controls using `<asp:TemplateField..>` or `<asp:BoundField ..>`

if you don't want to create `<asp:label ..` control for each columns of your gridview, you can simply use `<asp:BoundField ..>` and specify the width for the column using `ItemStyle-Width` property as below

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Features" HeaderText = "Features" ItemStyle-Width="400px"/>
```